# How Should I Store Data In SubSchemas in MongoDB and Node JS?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

In MongoDB, you store data by writing a schema and you use to do all your operation through some routing. My question is how should I store user data. Something like this:

```
const Page = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String
    Password: String
    lists: [{
        list_name: String,
        etc.
    }]
});
```

This is the way that I want to do it because no one else would be able to access anyone else's Lists. My Issue is let's say they update a certain list_name how would I update ONLY that certain list_name instead of updating everything. Im sort of new to MongoDB so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to get the index of the certain list_name (see $indexOfArray), then update value of that index. These links may help you, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/, 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/. Note that the $indexOfArray function returns the index of the first match. So if you want to update all name, you need to repeat the update process many times.

Answer (score 0):

*do thaun* helped me out by linking me to the docs. After looking at the docs I found a bunch of things that I was not using. With that being said here is the Schama that I ended up using.

```
const Task = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {type: String, required: true}
})

const Page = new mongoose.Schema({
    list_name : {type: String, unique: true},
    task: [Task]
});
```

For accessing the Task schema for a post I did this.

```
router.post('/lists/:list', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(await Question.findOne({_id: req.params.list}))
        const question = await Question.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.list}, {"$push": {task:{"text": req.body.text}}}, {new:true})

        if (!question)
            return res.status(404).json({})
        else
            return res.status(200).json(question)
            
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({"error":error})
    }
})
```

The get was a little bit more tricky because I couldn't find use findOne so I used a for loop. here is the code for the get.

```
router.get('/lists/:list/:task', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const _list = req.params.list 
        const _task = req.params.task
        console.log(_task)
        const question = await Question.findOne({_id: _list})
        for (let index = 0; index < question.task.length; index++) {
            if(req.params.task = question.task[index]._id)
                return res.status(200).json(question.task[index])
        }
        return res.status(404).json({})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({"error":error})
    }
})
```

I hope this helps someone because it was a bit annoying to get this information. Cheers!